# Angular Routing to different paths for one component

Tags: angular, routes

I have a page called 
http://example.com/consultation which represents the landing page (first page) of angular in my site, and the routes are as shown below.
The Question is: when the link is http://example.com/consultation (without anything after `consultation` i need to distribute routing randomly to `ask-question` and `service-page`. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'consultation',
        component: OnlineConsulationComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'ask-question', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'ask-question', component: AskQuestion },
            { path: 'service-page', component: ServicePage },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'ask-question' }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your redirects should have a slash in front

redirectTo: '/ask-question'

Comment: Thanks @David, but does this make the random routing to two links?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it from the OnlineConsultationComponent ngOnInit function. Just check the route there and if you don't detect 'ask-questions' or 'service-page' inside the active route, then reroute to one of those two chosen randomly. There is no way of doing this through the router directly.

You can also achieve this same behavior with a guard if you don't want to dont want to do it inside the component.

Comment: Lol, i just saw this is a two year old question. Hope this helps someone anyways.